# Как правильно распарсить xml sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xmlparser, xquery

Подскажите как правильно распарсить xml не зная названий его полей, но зная что он без уровня вложенности?

Например есть такой xml:

```
<id>37</id>
<order>84018</order>
<city>56</city>
<country>20</country>
<date>2018-02-01</date>
```

Ну и нужно чтобы на выходе получилось вот так:

```
+------+--------+---------+---------+------------+
| id   | order  | city    | country | date       |
+------+--------+---------+---------+------------+
| 37   | 84018  | 56      | 20      | 2018-02-01 |
+------+--------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью динамического [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), который позволяет поменять местами столбцы со строками в таблице, можно добиться требуемого результата

Вот полный рабочий пример:

```
DECLARE @XML as xml

SELECT @XML = 
'
<root>
<id>37</id>
<order>84018</order>
<city>56</city>
<country>20</country>
<date>2018-02-01</date>
</root>
'

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable

 create table #tempTable
    (
    NodeName nvarchar(max),
    NodeValue nvarchar(max)
    )

INSERT INTO #tempTable (NodeName, NodeValue) 
(SELECT 
    a.b.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as NodeName,
    a.b.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') As NodeValue
    FROM @xml.nodes('//*[not(*)]') AS a(b)
    )

Declare @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@SQL  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

Set @Cols = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(NodeName) 
                    From  #tempTable
                    For XML Path(''), Type
                   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')

Set @SQL = 'Select * From #tempTable
            Pivot (
                   max(NodeValue)
                   For [NodeName] in (' + @Cols + ')
                  ) p '

Exec (@SQL)
```

Как это работает:

1. Создаем временную таблицу, куда сохраняем имя xml элемента и его значение узлов, полученных c использованием функции [nodes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) для типа данных xml.  Строка запроса, равная `//*[not(*)]` означает - выбрать все элементы, за исключением элементов, у которых есть дочерние элементы. Тем самым, мы исключаем элемент `root` из выборки, он нам не нужен. В этой строке у нас два столбца, в одном из которых содержится название xml элемента, в другом - его значение
2. Объединяем все значения столбца `NodeName` в одну строку, разделенных символом "," и сохраняем в переменной `@Cols`. Строка с названиями столбцов необходима для выполнения операции PIVOT. Данные строки столбца `NodeName` должны стать строками.
3. Применяем наконец сам PIVOT для конвертации строк и столбцов к нашей созданной временной таблице - для каждого столбца в переменной `@Cols` выбираем соответствующее максимальное значение поля `NodeValue`.
    Применяем агрегатную функцию для всех строк, где значение поля `NodeName` из строки изначальной таблицы равно имени столбца из набора `@Cols`. В нашем примере повторяющихся строк нет, все значение в столбце `NodeName`уникальны, но агрегатная функция необходима, я использую функцию [max](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql).

В результате получаем перевернутую таблицу в том виде, в котором нам необходимо.

Comment: Удалось самому решить ,но ваше решение более элегантное, скажите а как обойти:
"Не удалось удалить таблица "#tempTable", так как он не существует или отсутствуют разрешения."

через if object_id('#tbl', 'u') is not null - тоже работа некорректная...

Comment: @noanother, добавил проверку на необходимость удаления темповой таблицы, если она существует.

Comment: А если строк будет несколько ?
`<root>
     ...
</root>
<root>
     ...
</root>`

Comment: если рутовых элементов будет несколько, то тогда данный способ работать не будет. Можно сделать цикл по рутовым элементам, где для каждого рутового элемента выполнять эту процедуру. Только результаты складывать еще в одну временную таблицу, которая будет содержать набор столбцов, который мы получили и сохранили в переменную @Cols.

Comment: Алексей, не могли бы расписать последний select, не могу понять как он работает. И как быть если к примеру '<' id' >37
...
...
...
'<' /id' >' Или '<' id val=37 /' >'

Comment: @noanother достаточно просто прописать первичным ключом в отношении не имя тега, а имя тега в паре со значением, и потом уже из этой таблицы создавать виды либо по значениям, либо по тегам

Answer (score 1):

Непомню чтобы можно было распарсить XML у которого некорректно  закрываются тэги, если это поправить то можно так:

```
DECLARE @XML as xml

SELECT @XML = 
'
<root>
<id>37</id>
<order>84018</order>
<city>56</city>
<country>20</country>
<date>2018-02-01</date>
</root>
'

SELECT
    x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as a,
    x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as b 
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[not(*)]') AS x(y)
```

и развернуть динамическим PIVOTом.